# Want to find the Regex pattern for Expression

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I want to validate with REGEX pattern with the given data and also with the correct position of the slash in between.

Please help me with the REGEX pattern.

```
ABC/090928/CCT001
```

I tried with the following pattern, but it doesn't correctly validate it .

> "^[a-zA-Z^/^0-9^/^a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

My code:

```
public class MsgIdCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]*/[0-9]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]$*";
        String data = "ABC/090928/CCT001";
        System.out.println(data.matches(regex));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to create the pattern youself? If so show us what you tried.

Comment: "^[a-zA-Z^/^0-9^/^a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

Comment: What do you think `[]` and `^` represent?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong , I guess both represent start of the character, P Shemo

Comment: What do you mean by "start of the character"?

Comment: You should read about `[]` [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Try to change your regex to something in form of `^[...]*/[...]*/[...]$*`

Comment: ^ Matches beginning of line.   [...]Matches any single character in brackets.

Comment: I'd suggest `[...]{n}` to match the exact number of occurences.

Comment: thanks  for ur help , "^[a-zA-Z]*/[0-9]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]$*" I did this and it still didnt validate it

Comment: Can you show us how are you using this regex? Post short code example which doesn't work for you.

Comment: public class MsgIdCheck {
 
      
   public static void main( String args[] ){

    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]*/[0-9]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]$*"; 
    String data = "ABC/090928/CCT001"; 
    System.out.println(data.matches(regex));
   }
}

Comment: Don't post code as comment. Place it in your question.

Comment: ya just did that in the question

Comment: Perfect ,it just worked after *$. thanks P shemo and dly for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not match your question ("^[a-zA-Z]*/[0-9]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]$*" vs "^[a-zA-Z^/^0-9^/^a-zA-Z0-9]*$").

Second you did not put '$' at then end, you need to change it to

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]*/[0-9]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
```